# Generic with indexed argument of type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to have a generic that I can index by name while preserving typing.  It would be useful to be able to write:

```js
candidates.sort(compareByClosestTo("recieved", date))
```

I feel pretty close, but can't seem to complete this

```js
// generic comparison fn with index
type Dateable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: DateTime
};
const compareByClosestTo = <T extends Dateable<T>>(key: keyof T, date: DateTime) => 
  (l: T, r: T) => Math.abs(l[key].diff(date).milliseconds) - Math.abs(r[key].diff(date).milliseconds)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQbgXzgDMoIQ4ByAGwFcAPCAOwoG4AoNgek7gHMNGGKMADGcEWTCphAZybFGbGAE8weNJlQAjKhgA8WAHxwAvIjZw4AbQAKcYIzgBrDMohE4WALoAuFOmxcNnx2CUYZeAlwaQwAIWUAYSoIGQwIrAhTOAM4DDpMRgATGX9NHX0jQwAKF2U-WvdPABo4QoC-DUCQDABKU2MLOCqqPywWqFG%20k2MAWXQACwA6bRlhq1qvRcLgIiIqtswexZBgKipgVLDivoBaODmYJZWqqHXXTe3d-YCjk7OLjBXGQ9DjcOAyVDgXStdCoNhhCIwzAlMxWQaWTo4bqLEhkGanc6rAAcAE4ACwAVgAzABGHpNdGlLoYHGkED4-6rGkAJiplPpjMxuFZeIJFyqNKpRIA7GSAGwCywYgJYlnJESoKhVAVeNgHNLHVBgfbwaZDJBQQHADAANwwhT8hRg%20B6IPhTERAHdoE4UUiDSAjSb%20ua4JaRNa7Q7Ws7XYylQnE0rFnJYFUolJLfEkik0jAMlUAEThyP2wstIXY9Wa7Vx93heBCUhQLL6mSG40mlrAKbGKoWq22%202OmDdop5PzAF0gpOzpMp6AwdOSGLZ5KpdIQIsloeFctM1WLata10goA)

however this gives an error because it requires all parameters to be of type DateTime.  Is there any way to simply constrain the type of T[key] to type?

**EDIT**

5 minutes after posting this I came across [a hint here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40832) that led me to:

```js
function sortByClosest<K extends string>(data: Record<K, DateTime>[], key: K, date: DateTime): void {
  data.sort((l, r) => 
    Math.abs(l[key].diff(date).milliseconds) - Math.abs(r[key].diff(date).milliseconds))
}
```

However, I'd like to leave this open because I would really really like to know how to figure out typed generic indexing on callback factories (ie, is the top forms possible?)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJjgW) work for your use cases?  If not, please elaborate.  If so I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: well, now I just feel silly :-).  Yeah, that works perfectly, for some reason I couldn't see it (lack of coffee).  If you put that in an answer it'll get the almighty green checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem in your original `compareByClosestTo()` function is that there is no good *inference site* for `T`.  The `key` parameter is of type `keyof T`.  If you pass in, say, `"foo"` for `key`, you'd need the compiler to infer a type `T` for which `"foo"` is one of its keys.  The compiler *might* infer `{foo: DateTime}`, depending on how you use it, or it might give up and infer something like `{foo: any}` or even `{[k: string]: any}`.  The only thing you can expect the compiler to reliably infer from a value of type `"foo"`, is the string `"foo"` itself.

To that end, let's dispense with `T extends Dateable<T>` and instead look at `K extends PropertyKey`.  Then we can express `T` in terms of `K`: in this case, `{ [P in K]: DateTime }`, which is equivalent to `Record<K, DateTime>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)):

```
const compareByClosestTo = <K extends PropertyKey>(key: K, date: DateTime) =>
  (l: { [P in K]: DateTime }, r: { [P in K]: DateTime }) =>
    Math.abs(l[key].diff(date).milliseconds) - Math.abs(r[key].diff(date).milliseconds);
```

Let's see what happens when we call it:

```
const compareFn = compareByClosestTo("recieved", DateTime.local());
/* const compareFn: (l: {
    recieved: DateTime;
}, r: {
    recieved: DateTime;
}) => number */
```

Here, `K` is inferred to be `"received"`, and the resulting compare function is the `{received: DateTime}` type we want.  And so both of the following `sort()` calls work:

```
const works = dates.map(dt => ({ recieved: dt }))
  .sort(compareByClosestTo("recieved", DateTime.local()))

const stillWorks = dates.map((dt, i) => ({ recieved: dt, index: i }))
  .sort(compareByClosestTo("recieved", DateTime.local()))
```

because each of the arrays you're sorting have elements assignable to `{received: DateTime}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQbgXzgDMoIQ4ByAGwFcAPCAOwoG4AoNgYyYGd5vwqKBgBCATwDCVCDwx8sEOAF44AHgDScDHUyMAJjzgAFUmAywx6jGIB8ACgDW1gFxx1AGjh70GV2kw4IBgAlMo2bHBwdlSuSADaRnDAjG4Aun4+gXj4nlCxcAlJKerpKJm4BKFK4ZGRALLoABYAdKgARjzRcU5iqc16wEREdt6Ywc0gwFRUwLLc+jyhALRwDTAt7Z1Q3dZ9A0MjPuOT07MY8wbB7GwA9DdwPKjgVHijqFy88KNyygURZQFcM0SGQ6lMZp0ABwATgALABWADMAEZgu5-v5sECQSAwadOsiAEyIhFouAY8pBYGkXHg2Z2ZGIyEAdlhADY0RTAVTpJxUFQ7JzUmxvjwJqgwCN4NUokhhJxgBgAG4YPSuPTwfDBYIceZ8OACMBCDAAMRSKkNxvEUhkchgCjsACJ5YqVXpHZ5MVlmrz+YKrrcAFQGz4hwTCM2uaKxf6RF3K1UZbkYdg5OB5RCx9PnV2JgFYoKpqo2OCMGggNrmOCBm660MAd2gDkMKlF4slGrCsuzCoTaq8mu1-2aPGgMDsluE1uksnkECd8bdHvz3t9Au1Oo+jH1fHBAHUmy2vD4xSAJXYpZ5gMXu4u8xqr-ptK5gJUdZER2OJ2QjVPJDO7QdZ0cz7ZcvSBNd-R1IA)

Comment: Thanks much for both the answer and the explanation!  It was extremely helpful to change the framing of the question.  Generics have come a long way since C++ :-)